# Why am I getting a linker error when I try to link something using std::format()?

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, c++23

I'm using an example from Chapter 1 of "Professional C++, Fifth Edition" by Marc Gregoire, with adaptations I've added so that Intellisense in VSCode won't vomit:

employee-module.cppm:

```cpp
export module employee;

export struct Employee {
  char firstInitial;
  char lastInitial;
  int employeeNumber;
  int salary;
};
```

employee.cpp:

```cpp
#ifdef __INTELLISENSE__
#include <iostream>
#include <format>
#include "employee-module.cppm"
#else
import <iostream>;
import <format>;
import employee;
#endif

using namespace std;

int main() {
  Employee anEmployee;
  anEmployee.firstInitial = 'J';
  anEmployee.lastInitial = 'D';
  anEmployee.employeeNumber = 42;
  anEmployee.salary = 80'000;

  cout << format("Employee: {}{}", anEmployee.firstInitial,
                 anEmployee.lastInitial)
       << endl;
  cout << format("Number: {}", anEmployee.employeeNumber) << endl;
  cout << format("Salary: ${}", anEmployee.salary) << endl;
}
```

And here's my Makefile, in case there's something I'm missing there:

```
CXX_VERSION = 23

CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++$(CXX_VERSION) -fmodules-ts
EXE = employee hello
SYSTEM_MODULES =    fstream filesystem thread algorithm any array atomic barrier bit bitset charconv chrono compare complex concepts condition_variable coroutine deque \
                    exception expected format forward_list functional future initializer_list istream iomanip ios iosfwd iostream iterator latch limits list locale map \
                    memory memory_resource mutex new numbers numeric optional ostream queue ranges ratio regex scoped_allocator semaphore set shared_mutex \
                    source_location span sstream stack stacktrace stdexcept stdfloat stop_token streambuf string string_view syncstream system_error tuple type_traits \
                    typeindex typeinfo unordered_map unordered_set utility valarray variant vector version execution random spanstream
.PHONY = all clean system-modules

default: all

all: $(EXE)

employee: employee-module.o employee.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

hello: hello.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^

%.o: %.cppm
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -x c++ $^

clean:
    rm -f $(EXE) *.o

deepclean: clean
    rm -rf gcm.cache/

$(SYSTEM_MODULES):
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -x c++-system-header $@

system-modules: $(SYSTEM_MODULES) | gcm.cache/
```

Building it gives me the following output, terminating on a linker error when it tries to link the final executable:

```
$ make
g++ -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -c -x c++ employee-module.cppm
g++ -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -c employee.cpp
g++ -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -o employee employee-module.o employee.o
/usr/bin/ld: employee.o: in function `unsigned char std::__detail::__from_chars_alnum_to_val<false>(unsigned char)':
employee.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8__detail25__from_chars_alnum_to_valILb0EEEhh[_ZNSt8__detail25__from_chars_alnum_to_valILb0EEEhh]+0x12): undefined reference to `std::__detail::__from_chars_alnum_to_val_table<false>::value'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:18: employee] Error 1
```

The system modules are all built and in `gcm.cache/` as expected (I'd get compiler errors if they weren't).

My first thought was that somehow libstdc++ isn't getting linked in, so on a hunch I added `-lstdc++` to the command line for the build and link steps, but I got the same result.

Furthermore, I rewrote the program to use just `cout` and put the variables in the stream directly, and avoid the use of `format()` altogether. It builds, links, and runs exactly as expected with no errors, even when I leave `-lstdc++` out of the command line.

For the record, the `"hello"` target in the Makefile builds, links, and runs just fine, it's a straightforward `"Hello, World!"` program using `<iostream>`.

So, then I googled the (unmangled) symbol names, hoping that would provide some insight. As far as I can gather, `std::detail::from_chars_alnum_to_val` is part of the `charconv` module, so I built it, added `import <charconv>;` to `employee.cpp`, and tried again. Compiled fine, but same linker error.

Next, I decided to just go wild and built every standard library module (thus the ridiculously long `SYSTEM_HEADERS` variable). No dice, same linker error.

Is there something fundamental I'm missing?

I'm on Slackware Linux current, 64-bit Intel, g++ 13.2.0, binutils 2.41

Comment: I wouldn't bother trying to use standard library modules until your compiler supports the standardised version from c++23.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you either made the initials as strings or actually specified the type explicitly as c for char in format.

Comment: Fwiw, I tried to make the dependencies clearer in your Makefile which seemed to get me somewhere, but unfortunately, my g++ 13.2.1 ICEs unless I rebuild clean which makes this very slow - and forget about using `make -j` to build the system modules.  If I try that, it'll barf out errors all over.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah, there's a reason the list in $(SYSTEM_MODULES) is mostly but not completely alphabetical--I discovered in the process of testing things that the order in which they're built very much matters, I imagine parallel make would screw that up a lot.

Comment: @kalyanswaroop Good idea, I'll give that a shot when I get home tonight.

Comment: @AlanBirtles That's what I've done in practice just to be able to get on with things, but I also kind of want to see if there's something I can learn from this as well

Comment: @AnInfamousHistorian Yeah, the ICE is the main obstacle. I added `-flang-info-module-cmi` to `CXXFLAGS` to see what it's doing and if I do `g++ -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -flang-info-module-cmi -c -x c++ employee-module.cppm` it will output `employee-module.cppm:1:8: note: writing CMI ‘gcm.cache/employee.gcm’` - but neither the directory nor the file is created.  It doesn't help if I create the directory first either. Annoying. I know I got this working a few years/months ago.